# Hybris stuck in Localizing step during initializing

Tags: hsqldb, sap-commerce-cloud

Why does my hybris server after starting it, gets stuck during :"Localizing Types" step.

I click on initialize in the HAC.

The process gets stuck here as shown.

[image]

[image]

I get no logs as well.

Im using default HSQL of hybris.

This is what I get when I stop the server:

> tenant <<master>> not yet started - got no active datasource

Comment: How long have you waited ?

Comment: The Localize Types usually takes time. If you want you can switch to some other db like MySQL, to speed up the process.

Comment: its for MySQL DB(mysql 5.7) only, its taking so much time @Sanchit...Default HSQL initializing seems fine...

Comment: It makes me wait for hours @Benoit...sometimes it gets stuck overnight, without any progress

Comment: Have you tried with MySql ? How many extensions are loaded ? Have you created customized hooks for the initialization ?

Comment: currently im trying with MYSQL 5.7...Theres an red x mark near most of the custom extensions in HMC....Means they re not loaded...i get the stack trace as :  Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Table 'hybris_test.props' doesn't exist.. during initialize

Comment: Try with Mysql 5.6, there are issues with 5.7. Also don't forget to configure *innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0* otherwise performances are really low.

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me. I noticed that the message was:
[main] [TypeLocalization] 1 threads will be used to localize type system.
The system hangs forever.
I found that the virtual machine was of 1 CPU.

When I increased CPU to 16. The message became:
[main] [TypeLocalization] 16 threads will be used to localize type system.
and the step toke no more than 30 seconds!

Therefore, the solution is to increase CPU.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like your databse connection was interupted

Comment: during the Initialization, i can access the the db @KilleKat... i just give show tables;  to see if tables count are getting updated...how and what do u mean by connection interrupted...how to overcome it for Mysql DB?